# Find application path from inside a web method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webmethod

I'm implementing a web method inside an ASP.NET page to execute asynchronous calls. Now I need to know the physical application path of my web app.

I usually use `Request.PhysicalApplicationPath`, but how can I obtain the same information from inside a web method?

**NOTE** No `Request` or `Server` properties are available inside the web method...

Comment: maybe the following will work: HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath) . Or maybe HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've always used:

```
var rootPath = HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath;
```

you'll need to also add `using System.Web.Hosting;` in your class directives header

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `Server.MapPath("/")`?

EDIT:

Or perhaps `System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath()`?

Comment: Apologies, I am used to working with services that have a HttpContext available. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```